# fullcalendar defaultDate for specific view

Tags: view, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a view called timelineFourMonths and I need them to stay permanent. jan-apr, may-august, sept-dec. At the moment, when i am looking at february in the month view and switch to 4 month view, it will show me feb-may but i would need the calendar to switch to jan-apr.

i tried this:

```
 defaultView: Cookies.get('fullCalendarCurrentView') || 'timelineMonth',
                defaultDate: Cookies.get('fullCalendarCurrentDate') || null,            
/*  viewRender: function(view) {
            Cookies.set('fullCalendarCurrentView', view.name, {path: ''});
            Cookies.set('fullCalendarCurrentDate', view.intervalStart.format(), {path: ''});
            Cookies.set('fullCalendarStart', view.intervalStart.format(), {path: ''});
            },
        */
viewRender: function(view){if (view.name=='timelineFourMonths')
                { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment('2017-01-01'));} else {
                Cookies.set('fullCalendarCurrentView', view.name, {path: ''});
                Cookies.set('fullCalendarCurrentDate', view.intervalStart.format(), {path: ''});
                Cookies.set('fullCalendarStart', view.intervalStart.format(), {path: ''});      
                }
                },
```

i am using cookies to preserve current view and date on refresh. default code is commented out at the moment and i tried the if function. it works, i will figure something out to find out the current 4month period from current date but this is not the best solution because it doesn't let me navigate on the 4 month periods. it will always go back to the date set by `'gotoDate'`.

defaultDate did not work in view settings even if i disabled the cookies settings.